# Can we use class variable's value to a new variable using $this

Tags: php

Can we use class variable's value to a new variable name using `$this` without assigning class variable's value in any other variable?

Example:

```
public $classVariable = 'thisIsValue';

$classVariableValue = $this->classVariable;
$$classVariableValue  = 'some value';
echo $thisIsValue; // output: some value
```

Is there any way to assign value from `$this` object directly?

Comment: Try it. And tell us.

Comment: Are you talking about using variable variables in a OOP scenario? Try it

Comment: I tried but not able to do it without assign it another variable

Comment: like $$this->classVariable = 'some value';
its throwing an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Just use curly brackets (braces?) in this case

```
${$this->classVariable} = 'some value';
```

I've testet this with PHP 5.5.23